# XPath: select node based on other node's value

Tags: .net, xml, xpath

Suppose I have a list of items, each with its own `<id>` element. There is also a `<primaryId>` element (outside mentioned list) specifying which one of these items is 'primary'. How do I select 'primary' item's `<value>` element? Is it possible to do using XPath in .Net?

The result in the following example should be `<value>val2</value>`.

```
<root>
  <primaryId>2</primaryId>
  <items>
    <item>
      <id>1</id>
      <value>val1</value>
    </item>
    <item>
      <id>2</id>
      <value>val2</value>
    </item>
  </items>
</root>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Location paths in XPath can include conditions in `[]`.

So first select the primary id node:

```
/root/primaryId
```

Make it a condition, compare it with the id element in the context of the condition:

```
[id=/root/primaryId]
```

Use it to filter the item nodes:

```
/root/items/item[id=/root/primaryId]
```

And the complete expression:

```
/root/items/item[id=/root/primaryId]/value
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<xsl:value-of select="/root/items/item[id=/root/primaryId]/value"/>
```

Comment: Generally a description of what you are suggesting or what you have changed greatly improves an answer.

Comment: If result of 2x2 is asked, what else besides 4 is expected as an answer? It's a simple question about xpath and xpath (inside xslt) is an answer. It could not be any easier.

Comment: See ThW's answer above.

Comment: Do you mean that every answer to question about xpath should contain information about xpath basics?

Comment: The idea of Stackoverflow is that these questions have a wider use than just answering the immediate question of the asker. People use a search engine for a question and end up here. To me, the value of @ThW's answer is far greater to somebody searching for an answer with limited knowledge. In general, you will probably find your answers better received on SO if you are correct *and* include lots of details.

Comment: I can only second @JoelC, a correct answer might not have any explanatory value.